# Rails: common approach for handling exceptions in restful actions on objects that have been destroyed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

It is very common in Rails for an `objects_controller` controller to have RESTful `edit` and `destroy` actions like so:

```
def edit
  @object = Object.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  @object = Object.find(params[:id])

  @object.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

With an associated view that provides edit and destroy links like so:

```
<%= link_to "Edit the Object", edit_object_path(object) %>
<%= link_to "Delete", object, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

And it is easy to blow this up. If I open two browser windows, A and B, destroy an object with the "Delete" link in browser A and then press the "Edit" link in browser B, the `find()` in the `edit` action throws an exception.

**Updating to add Jakub's suggestion**

There are several ways to deal with this:

1. catch the exception and recover gracefully in the `edit` action
2. use `@object = find(:first, "conditions... etc.` and test the `@object` in the `edit` action
3. use a general 404

But seeing as this is such a common pattern, I would love to know how other folks deal with this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You edit your 404 page in `public/404.html` to be something reasonably friendly explaining that what the person is trying to access is not available anymore. That's the general solution. However your domain could allow for example soft-deleting and then you could offer to un-delete the record in the edit view. Checkout the Paranoid plugin for that (I'd implement it quite generally in a before_filter).

Comment: Thanks Jakub - this makes sense. The 404 seems like a good approach if the situation is unlikely, but it seems like a bad user experience in an application where very frequent edits could sometimes lead to the exception. I think in those cases one would want to be more specific with the error message back to the user. And thanks for the pointer to paranoid -- I'll check that out.